# Script for changing modification time of files and directories recursively

Tags: shell-script, files, find, timestamps, touch

I have many big folders with thousands of files in them and I want to use `touch`to set their modification times to be "original time"+3 hours.

I got this script from a similar thread in superuser:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in all/*; do
  touch -r "$i" -d '+3 hour' "$i"
done
```

so I'm guessing what I need is to make it work in any directory instead of a fixed one (so I won't need to edit the script everytime I want to run it somewhere different) and for it to able to find and edit files recursively.

I have little experience using Linux and this is my first time setting up a bash script, though I do know a thing or two about programming (mainly in C).

thanks you all very much for the help :)

Comment: Your question title talks about access time but you don't mention access time anywhere else in the body of your question. You mention modification time instead. I took the liberty of editing your question title to match the body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `find -exec` for recursive `touch`, with command line args for dirs to process.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in "$@"; do
    find "$i" -type f -exec touch -r {} -d '+3 hour' {} \;
done
```

You can run it like this:

```
./script.sh /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2
```

Comment: thanks for replying! So it will search through every directory inside both dir1 and dir2?

Comment: @Achus Yes, that's right.

Comment: For files and directories, remove the `-type` switch and only the access time, add the `-a` switch.

Answer (score 3):

The correct and complete answer is:

To modify **access time only** with the "**touch**" command, you must use "**-a**" parameter, otherwise the command will modify the modification time too. For example, to add 3 hours:

```
touch -a -r test_file -d '+3 hour' test_file
```

> From man touch:
>
> ```
> Update the access and modification times of each FILE to the current time.
>
> -a                     change only the access time
>
> -r, --reference=FILE   use this files times instead of current time.
>
> -d, --date=STRING      parse STRING and use it instead of current time
> ```

So, the file will have access time equal to old access time plus 3 hours. And the modification time will stay the same. You can verify this with:

```
stat test_file
```

Finally, **to modify access time only to an entire directory** and its files and subdirectories, you can use "**find**" command to traverse the directory and use "**-exec**" parameter to execute "touch" over each file and directory (just do not filter the search with the "-**type f**" argument, it'll not affect the directories).

```
find dir_test -exec touch -a -r '{}' -d '+3 hours' '{}' \;
```

> From man find:
>
> ```
> -type c     File is of type c:
>
>             d      directory
>
>             f      regular file
> ```
>
> and for -exec:
>
> ```
> -exec command ;
>           Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting  of  ';'  is  encoun-
>           tered.  The string '{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone,
>           as in some versions of find.  Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a '\') or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.   See  the  EXAMPLES
>           section  for examples of the use of the -exec option.  The specified command is run once for each matched file.  The command is executed in the starting directory.   There
>           are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the -execdir option instead.
> ```
>
> Just remember enclose the braces in single quote marks to protect them from interpretation as shell script punctuation. The semicolon is similarly protected by the use of a backslash, though single quotes could have been used in that case also.

Finally, to use it into a shell script like "yaegashi" said:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in "$@"; do
    find "$i" -exec touch -a -r '{}' -d '+3 hours' '{}' \;
done
```

And run it like "yaegashi" said:

```
./script.sh /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2
```

It'll search through every directory inside both dir1 and dir2 and change only access time for every file and subdirectory.